# jQuery Slideshow Next/Previous

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and I'm just wondering the easiest and most efficient way to create next/previous buttons to go through the slideshow. My code is as follows:

```
    run = setInterval("switchSlide()", 2000);

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#slideshow img:gt(0)').hide();

        $('#slideshow').hover(function() {
            clearInterval(run);
        }, function() {
            run = setInterval("switchSlide()", 2000);
        });

        $('#play').click(function() {
            run = setInterval("switchSlide()", 2000);
        });

        $('#stop').click(function() {
            clearInterval(run);
        });
        $('#previous').click(function() {
                    $('#slideshow img:first').fadeOut(1000).prev().fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('#slideshow');
                });

                $('#next').click(function() {
                    $('#slideshow img:first').fadeOut(1000).next().fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('#slideshow');
                });

    });

    function switchSlide() {
        $('#slideshow img:first').fadeOut(1000).next().fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('#slideshow');
    }
```

Comment: The click event for the next button is just the click event for the play button, but without setInterval.

Comment: Can you tell us which slideshow plugin/script you are using?

Comment: Yeah you're right the next button isn't the issue.. what about the previous button? @JonasG.Drange I'm not using a slideshow plugin. I want to do this on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming next() will get you the next image because this is what you do in switchSlide(). You can add a div element in your HTML

```
  <div id="next"></div>
```

then attach a click event to it which will call next(), essentially performing the same action as switchSlide()

```
  $('.next').click(function(){ 
     $('#slideshow img:first').fadeOut(1000).next().fadeIn(1000).end().appendTo('#slideshow');
   })
```

the same can be done for previous

Comment: you can use .prev() instead of next
whenever your looking for jQuery functions try using www.dochub.io it's a great resource for this kind of thing

Comment: thanks. ive added both of those but the previous button doesn't act as expected. it doesn't go to the previous images it just goes to another image.. not sure of the pattern.

Comment: can you make a little js fiddle with your code, then we can work on it through that

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Zp6Xz/4/
that should work. I added

    $('#previous').click(function() {
        $('#slideshow img:last').fadeOut(1000).prev().fadeIn(1000).end().prependTo('#slideshow');       
    })

Comment: still doesn't seem to go in the correct order though - http://jsfiddle.net/Zp6Xz/5/