# Using JQuery to Change Content

Tags: jquery, html

I have a JQuery function that changes the content being displayed based on what slide you want to view. You click one of three circles and then it changes, kind of like a slideshow. But, the only problem is that you HAVE to click one of the circles in order to change the content. I would like to also have a JQUERY function that causes the desired content to slide through automatically, maybe with some animation. How can I automate my code?

Live Website: http://www.getstatewideroofing.com

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/h5wVc/4/

My JQUERY (I am using 1.8.2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.circle1').click(function () {
    $('#slideshow img').replaceWith('<img src="images/roof.png"/>');
    $('#slideshow-bottom p').replaceWith('<p> Some text </p>');
});
$('.circle2').click(function () {
    $('#slideshow img').replaceWith('<img src="https://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-
ash4/313870_456560374416571_509297138_n.jpg"/>');
    $('#slideshow-bottom p').replaceWith('<p>Some text</p>');
});
$('.circle3').click(function () {
    $('#slideshow img').replaceWith('<img src="http://i.imgur.com/1hxQNiw.jpg"/>');
    $('#slideshow-bottom p').replaceWith('<p>Some text</p>');
});
});
```

Comment: `$('#slideshow-bottom p').html('your string');` ? http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: Instead of replacing the content, why not have all three slides on the HTML and hide/show/animate the container?

Comment: Like Adrian said, try having your slides already on page. Do some css styling for example with absolute position and z-index. To automate your animations wrap them into a interval.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how you might build your auto-scroll functionality. Note, the show won't restart (I've left that for you to do) - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11797291/jquery-slideshow-next-previous) is a good place to go for help. The example I built will automatically start the slideshow and continue on to the next item in line. What you will need to do is append the `currentItem` (see my code) to the end of an array so that there is always a "next" slide in line. This code, and the hints above should be enough for you to build what you are looking for.

```
$(function() {
    setInterval(update, 2000);
});

function update() {
  var ItemToLoad = currentItem.next();
  ItemToLoad.trigger('click');
  currentItem = ItemToLoad;
}
```

**Working Example**
http://jsfiddle.net/h5wVc/20/

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments that it is better to have your slides available on the page and use css / javascript to animate and display them accordingly, a very simple way to achieve what your question asked though is to set an initial marker, then use setInterval to simulate a click on the next slide in the group. Something like

```
var marker = 1;

var imgclick = function() {  
    marker = ( marker === 3 ? 1 : ++marker );
    $('.circle'+marker).click();
};

window.setInterval(imgclick,1000);
```

The integer after the call to imgclick is the delay before the next click is simulated in ms and the loop will reset after the third slide (although you could easily change this to accomodate any number of slides by using

```
marker = ( marker === $("[class^=circle]").length ? 1 : ++marker );
```

i've updated your fiddle to show this working - http://jsfiddle.net/h5wVc/28/